# 2 similar tables with an indexed category_id - 2 different queries generated by Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.4

I'm using: Rails 3.2.13 and PostgreSQL 9.4.7

I have 2 product tables, `AProducts` and `BProducts.` Both tables have a `category_id` integer which is an indexed column, and both tables have several million records.

When I query `AProducts` by `category_id`, the response is quick and uses the index, but when I query `BProducts` the response is very very slow, and it uses a sequential scan instead of using the index. I'm trying to figure out why this is happening for `BProducts`, given that the table and model is nearly idential to `AProducts`. Here are the results from EXPLAIN:

```
irb(main):2290:0> BProduct.where(:category_id => 700).explain

  BProduct Load (219696.7ms)  SELECT "b_products".* FROM "b_products" WHERE "b_products"."category_id" = 700
  EXPLAIN (1.3ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT "b_products".* FROM "b_products" WHERE "b_products"."category_id" = 700
=> "EXPLAIN for: SELECT \"b_products\".* FROM \"b_products\"  WHERE \"b_products\".\"category_id\" = 700\n                                 QUERY PLAN\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n Seq Scan on b_products  (cost=0.00..1791663.25 rows=926 width=2036)\n   Filter: (category_id = 700)\n(2 rows)\n"
```

The slow query above takes 219696.7ms, and doesn't use the index. The query below for AProduct is quick and DOES use the index.

```
irb(main):2289:0> AProduct.where(:category_id => 700).explain
  AProduct Load (51.0ms)  SELECT "a_products".* FROM "a_products" WHERE "a_products"."category_id" = 700
  EXPLAIN (1.2ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT "a_products".* FROM "a_products" WHERE "a_products"."category_id" = 700
=> "EXPLAIN for: SELECT \"a_products\".* FROM \"a_products\"  WHERE \"a_products\".\"category_id\" = 700\n                                                           QUERY PLAN\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n Index Scan using index_a_products_on_category_id on a_products  (cost=0.56..5448.33 rows=1359 width=883)\n   Index Cond: (category_id = 700)\n(2 rows)\n"
```

What I'm trying to figure out, is how can I make my BProduct lookups use the index and fetch the records with the same speed as AProduct, and why isn't that the default behavior I'm seeing?

Comment: You can run `psql` and type `\d a_products` and `\d b_products` and ensure indexes are exactly same

Comment: Both tables have an index: `"index_b_products_on_category_id" btree (category_id)` and `"index_a_products_on_category_id" btree (category_id)`

Comment: Ok, there are some reasons, why PG doesn't use indexes on big table. You can try to use `VACUUM ANALYZE` pg SQL command and then check plans again.

Comment: Then you can try `/*+ IndexScan(b_products) */ SELECT "b_products".* FROM "b_products" ...`

Comment: If no result, ask this question with `postgresql` tag only, providing table structure and rows count for both tables. Be ready to provide info about PG config and server params(memory)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your table is not really indexed?

Check this on rails console: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes(:table_name)`

You can also do it directly on postgres: `SELECT indexname FROM pg_indexes;`

Comment: When I run `SELECT indexname FROM pg_indexes;` I see the proper indexes. When I run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes(:table_name)`, I get `[]` for all my tables, including a_product and b_product

Comment: Maybe try recreating both indexes from a Rails migration